# Matched looping in python

Tags: python, loops

This is probably a very easy thing to solve in Python, but I would appreciate anyone's help. I have two lists where I want to loop through but only for matched items:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listb = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']


for a in lista:
    for b in listb:
        print 'my first item is:', a, 'and my second item is:', b
```

This will print

```
my first item is: a and my second item is: a1
my first item is: a and my second item is: b1
my first item is: a and my second item is: c1
my first item is: b and my second item is: a1
my first item is: b and my second item is: b1
my first item is: b and my second item is: c1
my first item is: c and my second item is: a1
my first item is: c and my second item is: b1
my first item is: c and my second item is: c1
```

How can I make it print only:

```
my first item is: a and my second item is: a1
my first item is: b and my second item is: b1
my first item is: c and my second item is: c1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `zip` to loop over two list simultaneously

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listb = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']


for a,b in zip(lista,listb):
    print 'my items are:', a, b
```

output :

```
my items are: a a1
my items are: b b1
my items are: c c1
```

according to `index` matching will be done!

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes both lists are of equivalent size.

```
for i in range(0, len(lista)):
    print lista[i], listb[i]
```

Comment: I should add there are more "Pythonic solutions" to your question but this will help with your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). It will return an iterator of tuples of each pair of elements.

```
>>> for z in zip(lista, listb):
...   print('my items are: {}, {}'.format(*z))
...
my items are: a, a1
my items are: b, b1
my items are: c, c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `zip`. What zip does is it maps items in your lists. For for e.g. items at index 0 after zip will be `(a,a1)` and so on.

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listb = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
for a in zip(lista,listb):
    print ('my items are:', a)
```

Comment: what if i need to put the two items in two separate places. for example: 
        print 'my first item is:', a, 'and my second item is:', b

Comment: Just add another variable in the for loop and print it